# why do I get the following error in get request

Tags: python, string, http, get, python-requests

I have code like this :

```
import requests
import xmltodict

Locations = ['http://129.94.5.93:49154/setup.xml', 'http://129.94.5.92:49154/setup.xml', 'http://129.94.5.93:49154/setup.xml', 'http://129.94.5.92:49154/setup.xml', 'http://129.94.5.95:80/description.xml']

for item in Locations:
    r = requests.get(item)
    reply = xmltodict.parse(r.text)
```

this gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "ssdpxml.py", line 57, in <module>
    r = requests.get(item)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

But it works when I do this:

```
r=requests.get('http://129.94.5.95:80/description.xml')
```

**Why do I get the above mentioned error??**

Comment: Check if you really import `requests` and you don't shadow this module.

Comment: sorry accidentally pressed delete ... But yes I am importing requests ... how does one shadow a module

Comment: @sikhvir Try `import requests` and then `print requests.__file__` or `print requests.__path__`. Or `print dir(requests)` what shall show the functions etc. from that module. If they differ from what you expect, you in fact imported something different, the `__file__` could tell you from where. This is shadowing - another module comes in play, you import it and it hides access to the one you intended to import.

Comment: @sukhvir, sounds like you might have defined a local string variable called `requests` that is shadowing your imported module, like the other commenters suggested.

Comment: @Addison that was it.. I am just gonna go and crawl under a rock now